# How to make chrome show the browser while resizing?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to make Chrome show you the website changing live as you're resizing it?

In every tutorial I see online of people using Chrome while developing the browser shows you live what the site will look like as you resize it. On mine however it just shows a window border until the mouse is released and then it shows the website again. Not sure where the setting is to turn it on? I've tried googling around and nothing I found was related..

Comment: This doesn't depend on chrome but instead is controlled by the OS.

Comment: Ah so it's not in Windows 7? Hm. Or I wonder where it is in the OS

Comment: My windows does it IIRC, though I'm not booted into windows at the moment so I cant confirm.

Comment: Huh. I wonder if there's some setting I need to tick. Not on a low end system by any means, 4 monitors, killer GPU/CPU. It's driving me insane trying to find it lol